# Excluding system files in file.lists() in java

Tags: java, file-io

I am getting list of file using method `File.listFiles()` in `java.io.File`, but it returns some system files like (`.sys` and `etc`).. I am in need of excluding all system related files (Windows, Linux, Mac) while returning lists. Can any one solve my issue?

Comment: How to you define "system files"?

Comment: Can you not filter the resulting list yourself to exclude the files you don't want?

Answer (score 3):

I'd implement a simple `FileFilter` with the logic to determine, if a file is a system file or not and use an instance of it the way [AlexR showed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897999/105224). Something like this (the rules a for demonstration purposes only!):

```
public class IgnoreSystemFileFilter implements FileFilter {

   Set<String> systemFileNames = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("sys", "etc"));

   @Override
   public boolean accept(File aFile) {

     // in my scenario: each hidden file starting with a dot is a "system file"
     if (aFile.getName().startsWith(".") && aFile.isHidden()) {
       return false;
     }

     // exclude known system files
     if (systemFileNames.contains(aFile.getName()) {
       return false;
     }

     // more rules / other rules

     // no rule matched, so this is not a system file
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a general solution to this.  For a start, operating systems such as Linux and MacOS don't have a clear notion of a "system file" or any obvious way to distinguish a system file from a non-system file.

I think your bet is to decide what you mean by a system file, and write your own code to filter them out.

Answer (score 2):

Generally filtering of file lists is done by using file filter.

```
    new java.io.File("dir").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                            // add here logic that identifies the system files and returns false for them.

        }
    });
```

The problem is how do you define system files. If for example you want to filter out all files with extension `.sys` it is simple. If not please define your criteria. If you have difficulties to implement your criteria please ask specific question.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, some operating systems do not have a definition for *"system file"*.

However, if you are using Java 7, there is a new extension called [NIO.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) which might help you under Windows:

```
Path srcFile = Paths.get("test");
DosFileAttributes dfa = Files.readAttributes(srcFile, DosFileAttributes.class);
System.out.println("isSystem? " + dfa.isSystem());
```